# Asp.Net Server.Transfer problem with Toolkit ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager, server.transfer

I'm working on a site which has a toolkitscriptmanager in the master page.  My problem lies when navigating to a page which performs a server.transfer.  I'm actually also using url redirects, but from what I can tell, that doesn't have any bearing on the problem.

If I change code to Response.Redirect, the page redirects fine, but that's not the functionality I'm looking for, I need to keep the SEO friendly urls.

For example - say in the code of Page1.aspx there's a Server.Transfer to Page2.aspx. What I've diagnosed, is that the Script Manager adds a script reference to the page your'e browsing. So, If I were to navigate straight to Page2.aspx, The script added is

`<script src="/Page2.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField... etc`

However, with the Server.Transfer, it's trying to find

`<script src="/Page1.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField... etc`

How can I tell the ScriptManager to use the final destination for the script file?  I've been researching trying to use some magic setting in the TSM but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging and testing, I was able to get this to work. I had to move my scripts defined in the head into the TSM, and make use of the CompositeScripts:

```
<act:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
            <CompositeScript>
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/js/jquery.1.4.2.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/js/jquery-ui.1.8.5.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/js/jlEmbed.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </CompositeScript>
        </act:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

What I find stringe is if I set CombineScripts=true, the TSM would compile all the js files into its own internal script - and then still place the script referencing the page it's on.  By turning CombineScripts=false, it still compiles the js files, does them individually, and also does so for the page script reference.